# C++ - merging classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

in my project there are 5 classes which define the configuration parameters of the project.
In each of these 5 classes, the parameters are for a great portion similar to each other - only the names are slightly different. I.e. in class1 I have paramA_1, in class2 paramA_2... in class5 paramA_5.

I cannot redesign these 5 classes, which are some sort of input for me.

Each of this class has a son. I'd like to create a base class for the sons, for example to define the behaviour connected with the almost similar config parameters like paramA_x above.

Code example:

```
// cannot edit these 2 classes
class configRegs_1 {
protected:
    int paramA_1;
};

class configRegs_2 {
protected:
    int paramA_2;
};

class class_1 : public configRegs_1 {
    void function();
};

class class_2 : public configRegs_2 {
    void function();
};

void class_1::function() {
    // do something with paramA_1
}

void class_2::function() {
    // do the same as class_1::function but using with paramA_2
}
```

What's the best approach to do this? I was thinking about an intermediate class, which unifies the shared parameters: how to do it?

I'd like to have some

```
class configRegs_generic {
protected:
    int paramA;
};
class class_generic : public configRegs_generic {
    void function();
};

void class_generic::function() {
    // do something with paramA
}

class class_1 : public class_generic, public configRegs_1 {
    ...
};

class class_2 : public class_generic, public configRegs_2 {
    ...
};
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are talking about without a simple code example and/or diagram.

Comment: as @cyber mentioned, your question is pretty vague...you need to post the code to give us some explaination. However, from what you have said you will probably need multiple inheritence. Because you are talking about sons and again, the base classes for the sons.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably creates a settings wrapper class that uses the above classes in a container (list/array/hash/map) on the class type and use the settings class (with corresponding getters and setters). This way you can access each class parameter something like:

configRegs_wrapper[x]->paramA

- *where x is number of configRegs.*

If such a solution works for you I can illustrate with a working code sample.